# Seeingly simple Word 2013 wildcard search and replace

Tags: microsoft-word, wildcards

I have a lot of references that I want to reformat the current format is

```
Hambrick, D., & Frederickson, J. 2005. Are you sure you have a strategy? Academy of Management Executive, 19(4): 51-62.
```

and I want to have parentheses around the year:

```
Hambrick, D., & Frederickson, J. (2005) Are you sure you have a strategy? Academy of Management Executive, 19(4): 51-62.
```

I am using Word 2013 with the "use wildcards" option, trying this as a "find what" string:

```
. ([0-9]{4}).
```

and it works nicely -- where I fail is in building the corresponding "replace with" string. I would think it should be

```
. (\1).
```

but that does not work. Word will always put the content of \1 before any of the dots, creating a line like:

```
Hambrick, D., & Frederickson, J2005. (). Are you sure you have a strategy? Academy of Management Executive, 19(4): 51-62.
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need to escape the parentheses? try `. \(\1\).`

Comment: When I try that, I get the error message "The Replace With text contains a group number whcih is out of range"

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying works for me, unless I'm doing something slightly different:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: OK, so I retried a couple of times, and it never worked correctly. Then I copied the text into a new document, and it worked flawlessly. Thanks everyone